# HTML5 video stutters on loop?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, video, playback

I have an HTML5 video element on my page, it's scaled to fill the entire background with the idea being that it will loop as it plays. This works fine in Chrome but Safari and Firefox have stutter on loop. It's a good half a second in Firefox. Any ideas?

Here's my markup for the video player:

```
<video id="vid" preload="auto" autoplay loop onended="this.play();">
  <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="vid.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

I've tried a number of things, like controlling the playback entirely with JS instead of relying on the browser to figure it out. But there's always the stutter. I don't think it's an issue with preloading because if I do it all locally the video loads instantly (obviously) but there's still the same loop. Is this just an issue inherent in these browsers?

I'm tempted to create two instances of the video and simply toggle them with JS after each finishes. It'd be really dirty but I'm not sure what my other options are.

Comment: Have you found some workaround for this problem? I'm facing the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately no, though I haven't looked in on it for a while. I did some looking around and most of the examples I found basically had that problem if you just sat and watched them for long enough.

One trick I found was that if you use a background image of the first frame first and then add the video after the page has loaded more (so you don't delay page load by streaming this video) it's more forgivable in some way.

But aside from potential JS fixes (restarting it via JS based on time or something) I never found a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue and I actually fixed it by putting the webm source before the mp4 source. That way it tried to load the webm video format first, and it had less stutters when I was testing it. mp4 and ogv files both had stutters in Firefox and it drove me nuts, so I was amazed when webm files seemed to work as intended.

```
<video id="vid" preload="auto" autoplay loop>
  <source src="vid.webm" type="video/webm"/>
  <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer. I'm not sure that Firefox supported WebM when I was fighting with this. But it doesn't surprise me that this would do it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing the audio track of the .mp4 during encoding. Not Ideal if you need the audio but it worked well in my case.